# castle windsor register all components implementing specific interface

Tags: castle-windsor

I have multiple components implementing IPollingService interface and i'd like to register them all by convention. By the way i don't see any component registered in the container and i cannot seem to resolve them. Any idea?

I tried the following but i cannot resolve them:

```
    public class PollingServicesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    { 
        public void Install( IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store )
        {
            var registrations = Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IPollingService>().WithServiceBase().AllowMultipleMatches();

            container.Register( registrations );
        }
    }

   static void Main( string[] args )
   {
        var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
        container.Install( new PollingServicesInstaller() );

        var pollingServices = container.ResolveAll<IPollingService>();
        //pollingServices is empty at this point but i got several implementations in this assembly
   }

  public class ServiceMock1 : IPollingService
    {
        public int PollingInterval { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }

        public ServiceMock1()
        {
            this.PollingInterval = 3000;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine( Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId );
            Console.WriteLine( "doing stuff " + this.PollingInterval );
        }
    }
```

As you can see from the screenshot 0 implementations are loaded.

[image: Screenshot]

I also noticed that CastleWindsor do not find my installer if i try to run installers this way:

```
 container.Install( FromAssembly.This() );
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  Are your `IPollingService` implementations not public?  Could you post one that you would expect to be resolved?

Comment: Is PollingService installer in the same assembly as the classes implementing IPollingService ?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk all my implemtantions are public and in the same assembly.  I edited my post with one implementation example i actually use

Comment: Try replacing WithServiceBase with WithServiceAllInterfaces.

Comment: @Marwijn nothing has changed. I also noticed CastleWindsor do not discover my installer by convention. Do this suggest something to you?

Comment: I tried the following gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/be7f888e3a15f3a65038 in which your code seems to work fine. To try it just create a new C# project and install windsor using nuget (version 3.3). Can you create a gist that fails ?

Comment: Dear @Marwijn i did what you told me (new project etc) but the Debug.Assert fails. Error is probably due to Castle Windsor installation itself. I will try to fix this and eventually  ask for help again. thank you

Comment: Did you install the latest Windsor package (3.3) with nuget ?

Comment: yes I did, i also tried the 3.2.1 one.. just in case... same behavior,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72073/discussion-between-sam-and-marwijn).

Comment: Today i think I found out what the problem is. Read the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My classes and interfaces are all public but declared inside Program class, that is internal by default and so are not discovered. [See the screenshot of the code in the question]

I think this is counterintuitive but is not necessarily a Castle.Windsor problem.

Should Castle.Windsor behave somewhat differently?

[Why is it allowed to declare a public class inside a internal class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652663/why-is-it-legal-to-declare-nested-public-types-inside-an-internal-type?noredirect=1#comment55079084_33652663)?