# Why is it legal to declare nested public types inside an internal type?

Tags: c#, .net, nested

Shouldn't it be forbidden to declare a nested type that is more accessible than the parent?

To expand on why i asked [this is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767992/castle-windsor-register-all-components-implementing-specific-interface/33652376#33652376)

Comment: Sounds like a matter of opinion to me. Note that the accessibility domain will still be internal. Do you believe you also shouldn't be able to declare new public methods in an internal type? If you don't, what's the difference between methods and nested types?

Comment: To expand on @JonSkeet's comment, a major benefit of this setup is that you can have a class be internal to start, build your methods as if it's public, and at a later date make it public in your library. There's really no downside to how it works today.

Comment: I have got no opinion, it just seems to me counterintuitive but that's it. I think programming language designer did have a strong motivation behind this choice and id' like to know what's the reasoning behind this.

Comment: What if you have deeper nesting?
For example with the code `namespace N { public class C { protected class D { public class E { } } } }`, the inner-most class `E` is accessible to anyone who can see `D`, which is in turn anyone inside `C` or inside classes (possibly in other programs) deriving from `C`. In this case there is really no other modifier you can use for `E`. So this shows a situation where nested-public inside something non-public makes sense.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i see your point, btw, in general, If something nested has to be public at any level i consider to promote it (e.g. i do not make it nested if possible).

Comment: I see your point. However, the framework sometimes uses `public` nested classes. Example: `Dictionary<string, string>.KeyCollection.Enumerator` is a public struct inside a public class inside a public class.